# Is should be 12 size of mentioned class?

Tags: c++, memory-management, operating-system

Please share your thoughts about this:

```
 class A
   {
     union {
       unsigned int _dummy_drc[2];
       struct {
         unsigned int _trans_drc :1;
         unsigned int _cap_drc :1;
         unsigned int _fanout_drc :1;
         unsigned int _trans_drc_index :10;
         unsigned int _cap_drc_index :10;
         unsigned int _fanout_drc_index :10;
      };
    };
  };
```

Is it should be 12 and why?

Comment: With 'unsigned int _fanoutk_drc_index :31;'  12, without it 8.

Comment: Why don't you `sizeof` it and find out? The size of `unsigned int` is compiler and platform dependent, so it isn't necessarily the same on all systems.

Comment: I know that. The problem is different:
GCC for unsigned int returned 4, so I think sizeof for  class mentioned below should be 8:
         class A {
           union {
           unsigned int _dummy_drc[2];
             struct {
               unsigned int _trans_drc :1;
               unsigned int _cap_drc :1;
               unsigned int _fanout_drc :1;
               unsigned int _trans_drc_index :10;
               unsigned int _cap_drc_index :10;
               unsigned int _fanout_drc_index :10;
               unsigned int _drc_unused :31;
             };
           };

Comment: Bit fields are implementation defined and their size/layout will be different on different compilers and even different versions of the same compiler (basically avoid using for portable code).  `sizeof` is the only way to observe the size of `class A` and if you upgrade your compiler it may change.  Also note that in C++ (but not C) reading from a union member that was not the last member written to is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Please update your question to show any new code rather than putting it in comments -- your original question has no mention of the 31 bit `_drc_unused` field.  In spite of the implementation defined behaviour intrinsic to bitfields I would hallf expect the additon of the `_drc_unused` field to increase the size from 8 to 12 in this case for the simple reason that a single bitfield cannot span an `unsigned it` boundary (if I remember correctly).

Comment: Regarding my previous comment it appears I hadn't remembered *quite* correctly.  The standard states in *[**class.bit**]* "[ Note: Bit-fields straddle allocation units on some machines and not on others. Bit-fields are assigned right-to-left on some machines, left-to-right on others. — end note ]".  So even that aspect of bitfields is implementation defined.

Answer (score 1):

> Is should be 12 size of mentioned class? [sic]

The size of the structure depends on many platform dependent things. For example, it depends on the size of (`unsigned`) `int`. On some system it could be 1, while on another it could be more. It also depends on whether a bit field "straddles" multiple underlying objects or not. On some systems it does, on others it doesn't.

The size of `_dummy_drc` is `2 * sizeof(int)`, so the size of the class is at least 2.

On a system where `sizeof(int) == 4` and bitfields do not straddle multiple objects and fields are assigned left to right and `CHAR_BIT == 8`, the expected size of (the anonymous struct and therefore the union and therefore) the containing class would be 8:

```
|1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |p |6 |p     field position, p stands for padding
|1 |1 |1 |10|10|8 |10|22    field bits
|1 |2 |3 |13|23|32|10|32    cumulative bits since start of object
|1                |2        underlying integer position
```

---

PS. The union is ill-formed in C++, because it contains an anonymous member class.